# pandas multiindex - remove rows based on number of sub index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

Here is my dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"C1" : [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2], 
                            "C2" : [200, 158, 698, 666, 325, 224, 584], 
                            "C3" : [15, 99, 36, 14, 55, 62, 37]},
                           index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (3,0), (4,0)], 
                                                         names=['L1','L2'])))
```

df :

```
         C1      C2     C3
L1  L2          
0   0   0.5     200     15
1   0   0.9     158     99
    1   0.1     698     36
2   0   0.2     666     14
    1   0.3     325     55
3   0   0.5     224     62
4   0   0.2     584     37
```

I would like to keep the rows that only have one value in L1 subindex (0 in that case) in order to get something like that :

```
         C1      C2     C3
L1  L2          
0   0   0.5     200     15
3   0   0.5     224     62
4   0   0.2     584     37
```

Please, could you let me know if you have any clue to solve this problem ?

Sincerely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by first level with any column with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby(level=0)['C1'].transform('size').eq(1)]
```

Or extract index of first level by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and filter with inverted mask by `~` with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and `keep=False` for all dupes:

```
df1 = df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)]
```