# Drop rows where multi-index is some number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
      pid  ts
sid vid           
1   A    page1  t1
    A    page2  t2
    A    page3  t3
2   B    page1  t4
3   C    page1  t5
```

I want to drop all rows for each `sid` the size is equal to some number, lets say = 1

psuedo-code

```
for every sid in df:
    if sid.size() == 1:
       remove sid from df
```

The result would look like:

```
              pid   ts
   sid vid           
    1   A    page1  t1
        A    page2  t2
        A    page3  t3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `groupby` the first index level and `filter` the groups whith length greater than 1:

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda g: len(g)>1)
```

output:

```
           pid  ts
sid vid           
1   A    page1  t1
    A    page2  t2
    A    page3  t3
```

*NB. you could also use the level name: `df.groupby(level='sid').filter(lambda g: len(g)>1)`*

used input:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'pid': {(1, 'A'): 'page3', (2, 'B'): 'page1', (3, 'C'): 'page1'},
                    'ts': {(1, 'A'): 't3', (2, 'B'): 't4', (3, 'C'): 't5'}})
        .rename_axis(['sid', 'vid'])
     )


#            pid  ts
# sid vid           
# 1   A    page3  t3
# 2   B    page1  t4
# 3   C    page1  t5
```

Comment: this returned an empty df

Comment: @Sebazz44 please provide your dataframe as dictionary or dataframe constructor, the format in your question is ambiguous

Comment: I agree. It's kinda hard to see exactly what you're looking for, @Sebazz44.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952399/pandas-multiindex-remove-rows-based-on-number-of-sub-index the literal opposite of this, I want to remove sub-indexes (sid) where the size is equal to 1

Comment: @Sebazz44 how what I proposed is not working? It is with the provided example assuming you have a MultiIndex